# How to display png images in browser with resizing and scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, model-view-controller

We're designing an application that processes images and highlights certain parts by parsing co-ordinates. However, images being larger in size can't be displayed in single go. Also image can not be scrolled vertically as I've applied no formatting as of now, only horizontal scroll works.

Now the requirement is to display the full image with scrolls enabled. Also, the image size vertically and horizontally should be resized when the boxes on the top and side are expanded and collapsed.

E.g. This is how the page initially loads with the sidebar:

[image]

Now, we can resize it when the need for sidebar ends as highlighted so as to get the entire view to image after collapsing the bar in the image after this:

[image] 
[image]

Of course the top and side bar can be floating over the image or when the bars are expanded the image needs to be resized so as to not conceal any of its details.

We're developing this application in dot net MVC and image is displayed on the view. I'm not able to understand what would be the simplest approach to achieve this without using complex jQuery functions? And if there's no alternative to using jQuery then what other technologies in accordance to jQuery will be needed to achieve this? Is it also possible to achieve with simply HTML and CSS?

Comment: how do you realize the highlight?

Comment: I didn't understand the question. please can you be precise?

Comment: Your question is too broad. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).